# Not all code paths return a value. I was just wondering what was the fix to this?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I hover over the Index it has a red line underneath and says

> 'UnauthEnquiryController.index(UnauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel)': not all code paths return a value.

I was just wondering what was the fix to this?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(UnauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel unauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel)
{
    //unauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel.EnquiryType;
    //NEED TO ADD A METHOD THAT SENDS FILE TO CRM HERE
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (1 == 0) //take off
        {
            string fromAddress = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromEmail"]; //gets email from web.config file
                                                                                   //var toAddress = new MailAddress(); //need to get this from crm            

            var enquiry = DataAccessEnquiry.GetEnquiryCategoryEmail(unauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel.EnquiryType); //gets the to address based on CRm

            string UnauthEmailSubject = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UnauthEmailSubject"]; //gets subject from web.config file

            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(fromAddress, enquiry.Email); //put to address frrom variable declared above

            mailMessage.Subject = UnauthEmailSubject;

            StringBuilder mailbuilder = new StringBuilder();
            mailbuilder.AppendLine("First name: " + unauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel.FirstName);
            mailbuilder.AppendLine("Last name: " + unauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel.LastName);
            mailbuilder.AppendLine("Communication: " + unauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel.CCommmunication);
            mailbuilder.AppendLine("Email: " + unauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel.Email);
            mailbuilder.AppendLine("Confiirmation of email: " + unauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel.ConfirmEmailAddress);
            mailbuilder.AppendLine("Mobile telephone No: " + unauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel.MobileTelephoneNo);
            mailbuilder.AppendLine("Confiirmation of mobile telephone no: " + unauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel.ConfirmMobileTelephoneNo);
            mailbuilder.AppendLine("Alternative telephone no: " + unauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel.AlternativeTelephoneNo);
            mailbuilder.AppendLine("Confiirmation of alternative telephone no: " + unauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel.ConfirmAlternativeTelephoneNo);
            mailbuilder.AppendLine("I am a: " + unauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel.Profession);
            mailbuilder.AppendLine("Enquiry Type: " + unauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel.EnquiryType);
            mailbuilder.AppendLine("Your message: " + unauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel.YourMessage);


            if (unauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel.File != null) // this finds overall null
            {
                foreach (var file in unauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel.File) // loop through every File
                {
                    if (file != null) //Finds induvidual null
                    {
                        var extension = new FileInfo(file.FileName).Extension.ToUpper();
                        mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(file.InputStream, file.FileName));
                    }
                }
            }

            mailMessage.Body = mailbuilder.ToString();

            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
        }

        return View("Unauthsuccess", unauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel);
    }

    unauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel.Professions = DataAccessEnquiry.GetProfessionUnauthenticated();
    unauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel.EnquiryTypes = new List<EnquiryType>();
}
```

Comment: move  `return View("Unauthsuccess", unauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel);` to last line of the function.

Comment: What do you want to return if `ModelState.IsValid` is not `true`?

Comment: It means there's a potenial code path in your method that doesn't end with returning an `ActionResult`

Comment: return a View which would take them to the login page.

Comment: I want them to once all is complete to return to Unauthsuccess just for testing purposes

Comment: return must be there after if condition as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(UnauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel unauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel)
{
    //unauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel.EnquiryType;
    //NEED TO ADD A METHOD THAT SENDS FILE TO CRM HERE
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ...

        return View("Unauthsuccess", unauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel);
    }

    unauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel.Professions = DataAccessEnquiry.GetProfessionUnauthenticated();
    unauthenticatedEnquiryViewModel.EnquiryTypes = new List<EnquiryType>();

    //THIS path doesn't return value.
    //HERE return somethig
}
```

You return value only if  `if (ModelState.IsValid)` is true but what want you return if this is false?

Comment: *"//HERE return somethig"* - Not strictly necessary, and usually not the right thing to do anyway. When you check pre-conditions, and find that some of them aren't met, you often cannot return anything meaningful. You know what to do, when that happens.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have created a condition,

```
if(ModelState.Isvalid)
{
      {// LOTS OF CODE}
      return View(....);
}
```

But if

```
ModelState.Isvalid == false
```

is true then the function wouldn't return anything

Answer (score 0):

You are returning value in if condition only that's way its saying. You must have to return after if condition as well

Comment: You must have to return after if as well